# Tate twists and cohomology of $\mathbf{P}^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, etale-cohomology, motives, hodge-theory

I was wondering if anyone could give me some intuition as to why, for a smooth projective variety $X$ over $\mathbf{C}$ of complex dimension $d$, the Tate twist on $H^n(X(\mathbf{C}),\mathbf{Z})$ to be incorporated to have a pairing with $H_{d-n}(X(\mathbf{C}),\mathbf{Z})$ into $\mathbf{Z}(-d)$, is related to (tensor powers of) the cohomology group $H^2(\mathbf{P}^1,\mathbf{Z})\simeq H^1(\mathbf{G}_m,\mathbf{Z})$.

In other words, why does one often define $\mathbf{Z}(-1) := H^2(\mathbf{P}^1,\mathbf{Z})$? Is there some Kunneth formula lurking behind the scene? Should I think about $X(\mathbf{C})$ as a family $X(\mathbf{C})\times \mathbf{P}^1\to \mathbf{P}^1$? Is there a map $H^2((\mathbf{P}^1)^d,\mathbf{Z})\to H^d(X(\mathbf{C}),\mathbf{Z})$? Where does it come from?

I can understand the notation comes from $H_0(\mathbf{P}^1,\mathbf{Z})\simeq H_1(\mathbf{G}_m,\mathbf{Z})\simeq\pi_1^{\rm ab}(\mathbf{G}_m) =\pi_1(\mathbf{G}_m) := \mathbf{Z}(1)$, the reason I'm asking the question: even if there is $H_0(X(\mathbf{C}),\mathbf{Z})\to H_0(\mathbf{P}^1,\mathbf{Z})$, I see no map $X(\mathbf{C})\to\mathbf{P}^1$ in general. Unless somehow $X(\mathbf{C})$ can always be realized as the fiber over some point of $\mathbf{P}^1$ of some map $\mathcal{X}\to\mathbf{P}^1$, with $X$ homotopy equivalent to $\mathcal{X}$. Can one just choose $\mathcal{X} = X(\mathbf{C})\times\mathbf{P}^1$? (can it possibly be so simple? In algebraic geometry, this would amount to taking the trivial deformation of $X\to *$ to $\mathcal{X} \to\mathbf{P}^1$ along a fixed point $*\to\mathbf{P}^1$, and trivial deformations strike me as usually not so interesting). I'll appreciate any insight on the matter a lot

Thanks

Comment: It encodes $(2\pi i)^{-d} \int_{X(\mathbf{C}),i}$ (using $i$-oriented integration), which is independent of the choice of $i$. That is, such an operation applied to ${\rm{H}}^{2d}(X(\mathbf{C}), \mathbf{Z}(d))$ yields output in $\mathbf{Z}$. In effect, you shouldn't put the negative Tate twist where you do but rather absorb the positive Tate twist inside the cohomology (since $\mathbf{Z}(d)$ is naturally the orientation sheaf on $X(\mathbf{C})$).

Comment: There are various consistency checks for the twists: They should be compatible with weights of Hodge structures, and the weights in etale cohomology. But to see more directly the relation to $\mathbb{P}^1$, you can use $X\to \mathbb{P^n}\cong S^n\mathbb{P}^1\leftarrow (\mathbb{P}^1)^n$, where the first map is given by inclusion, and the second is a standard identification.

Comment: @DonuArapura I did consider $(\mathbf{P}^1)^n\to Sym^n(\mathbf{P}^1)\simeq\mathbf{P}^n$, but since the first map is not an isomorphism, how can this 'explain' the twist inside $H^{2n}$ to get the correct trace map $H^{2n}(X(\mathbf{C}),\mathbf{Z})\to\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: @nfdc23 Yes, I see. I was aware of this, although it's still unclear what role $\mathbf{P}^1$ plays. Whatever the answer, hopefully through an elaboration of Donu's comment, I'd be interested in seeing its counterpart in the language of orientation sheaves. I.e., the question may turn into 'how are the orientation sheaf on $(\mathbf{P}^1)^d$ and $X(\mathbf{C})$ related' ?

Comment: ironically enough, there's a positive Tate twist of weight $d$ missing in my second to last comment

Comment: Why are $\mathbf{P}^1$ or its powers regarded as playing any   distinguished role in the foundation? This seems unlikely. I wasn't aware that one "often" defines $\mathbf{Z}(-1)$ to be ${\rm{H}}^1(\mathbf{P}^1, \mathbf{Z})$; it seems more natural to define $\mathbf{Z}(1)$ to be $\pi_1(\mathbf{C}^{\times}) = \ker(\exp: \mathbf{C} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbf{C}^{\times})$ as you mentioned.

Comment: $\mathbf{P}^1$ and $\pi_1(\mathbf{C}^{\times})$ have little to do with one another, concerning your question, although I did see in the literature (esp. in $p$-adic Hodge theory, where one has no notion of topological fundamental gp for $p$-adic analytic spaces and formal schemes) and yet one has to introduce an appropriate notion of Tate twist, that indeed the "Tate object" (or Lefschetz motive) is defined by $\mathbf{Z}_p(-1) := H^2(\mathbf{P}^1,\mathbf{Z}_p)$.

Comment: This has actually nothing to do with $\mathbf{P}^1$, but rather it happens that $H^2(\mathbf{P}^1,\mathbf{Z}_p)$ ought to be the $p$-adic completion of the non-existent $\mathbf{Z}$-dual of $\pi_1(\mathbf{G}_m)$, where $\mathbf{G}_m$ is the $p$-adic analytic, respect. formal, multiplicative gp. Therefore, people often use $H^2(\mathbf{P}^1,\mathbf{Z}_p)$ as a replacement for $\mathbf{Z}_p(-1)$, and I agree it is somewhat misleading.

Comment: There are two parallel considerations to make. One: for $f : X\to *$ a proper map of $\mathbf{C}$-analytic spaces, consider the Verdier essential pullback $f^{!}$ evaluated on the orientation sheaf $\mathbf{Z}$ of the point $*$. If $X$ is $d$-dimensional and smooth, you can prove $f^{!}\mathbf{Z}\simeq\mathbf{Z}(d)[2d]$ (eg. invoking the fact that $f^!\mathbf{Z}$ must be the dualizing sheaf for the $\mathbf{Z}$-cohomology of $X$ and constructing the (unique!) Verdier trace concretely via integration.

Comment: (Using the Artin comparison thm in SGA4 as key input, you can even show that the derived $\ell$-adic completion of the iso $f^!\mathbf{Z}\simeq\mathbf{Z}(d)[2d]$ canonically agrees with the $\ell$-adic trace map.)
Two: for a proper smooth family $f : \mathcal{X}\to D^{\times}$ of $\mathbf{C}$-analytic spaces on the punctured complex unit disc $D^{\times}$, upon base-changing $f$ to the universal cover $\widetilde{D^{\times}}$ of $D^{\times}$, all fibers of $f':= f_{\widetilde{D^{\times}}}$ are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: There's an induced action of $\pi_1(D^{\times}) = \mathbf{Z}(1)$ on the cohomology of each such fiber (that under the $\ell$-adic Artin comparison and the smooth base-change thm is sent to the inertial action on geometric $\ell$-adic étale cohomology).
Your question ought to rather ask how such action is related to the orientation sheaf on each such fiber, possibly explaining the notation $\mathbf{Z}(d)$ for both $\pi_1(D^{\times})^{\otimes d}$ and $f^!\mathbf{Z}$. I'll never have the time to write an answer anytime soon. Unless somebody else does so, I will at some point.

Comment: You may want to look into Deligne's "Hodge II".

Comment: Another perspective: the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for $\mathbb{P}^1$ and its standard charts gives an isomorphism $H^1(\mathbb{G}_m) = H^2(\mathbb{P}^1)$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Tate twist is what we need to express Poincaré duality without making any choice. Such a choice appears in the choice of an orientation of the affine line minus the origin, and have shadows in the description of the Thom isomorphism, hence, in the description/construction of Gysin maps, trace maps, and so forth. A natural way to make this transparent goes through the theory of Chern classes. In what follows, when I write the symbol $=$, I mean that there is a canonical isomorphism, the construction of which does not involve any choice: it always comes by functoriality.

If we define $\mathbf Z(1)$ as the first homology group of the affine line minus the origin, then it is a free abelian group of rank one, and one defines $\mathbf Z(n)$ as a tensor product of $n$ copies of $\mathbf Z(1)$ for $n\geq 0$, and as the dual of $\mathbf Z(-n)$ for $n<0$. Given an abelian group $A$, one defined $A(n)=A\otimes\mathbf Z(n)$. Since, by definition, cohomology is the dual of homology, and since we are dealing with free groups, we have a canonical identification
$$H^1(\mathbf A^1-\{0\},\mathbf Z)=\mathbf Z(-1)\, .$$
By an elementary Mayer-Vietoris argument, one can deduce that $H^2(\mathbf P^1,\mathbf Z(1))=\mathbf Z$, but that is just a computation, not an explanation.

What precedes means that the classifying space of the topological abelian group $\mathbf C^\times=\mathbf G_m(\mathbf C)$ is not really a $K(\mathbf Z,2)$, but rather a $K(\mathbf Z(1),2)$. This is why we have Chern classes of line bundles
$$c_1:Pic(X)=[X,B\mathbf G_m]\to[X(\mathbf C),B\mathbf C^\times]=H^2(X,\mathbf Z(1))$$
(where $[A,B]$ means the homotopy classes of maps from $A$ to $B$ in the appropriate sense). This is used to prove the projective bundle formula. For a vector bundle $E$ on $X$ of rank $r$, with associated projective bundle $\mathbf P(E)$, if $t$ denotes the first Chern class of the tautological line bundle on $\mathbf P(E)$, then the map $(x_0,\ldots,x_{r-1})\mapsto \sum^{r-1}_{i=0}t^ix_i$ is an isomorphism:
$$\bigoplus_{i=0}^{r-1}H^{n-2i}(X,\mathbf Z(-i))=H^n(\mathbf P(E),\mathbf Z)$$
Now, given a closed immersion $i:Z\to X$ between smooth schemes over $\mathbf C$, one defines $H^n(X,Z)=H^n(Z,i^!(\mathbf Z))$. In other words, this is the $n$th cohomology group of the homotopy fibre of the restriction map $R\Gamma(X,\mathbf Z)\to R\Gamma(X-Z,\mathbf Z)$. The Thom isomorphism is a canonical identification:
$$H^n(X,Z)=H^{n-2c}(Z,\mathbf Z(-c))$$
where $c$ is the codimension of $Z$ in $X$. (When $i=s$ is the zero section of a vector bundle $E$ the Thom isomorphism is obtained from the projective bundle formula applied to the direct sum of $E$ and of the trivial line bundle. The general case follows from a deformation to the normal cone argument.)

For $X=\mathbf P^1$ and $Z=\{\infty\}$, this means that
$$H^2(\mathbf P^1,\{\infty\},\mathbf Z)=H^0(\{\infty\},\mathbf Z(-1))=\mathbf Z(-1)\, .$$
The meaning of all this is that $\mathbf Z(-1)$ is not the second cohomology group of the projective line. It is rather the second cohomology group of the projective line pointed at infinity. Of course, by homotopy invariance, there is a canonical isomorphism $H^2(\mathbf P^1,\{\infty\},\mathbf Z)=H^2(\mathbf P^1,\mathbf Z)$, but, in some sense, that is misleading: the canonical identification of $H^2(\mathbf P^1,\{\infty\},\mathbf Z)$ with the dual of $H_1(\mathbf A^1-\{0\},\mathbf Z)$ is through a (baby version of the) Thom isomorphism, which is yet another expression of the theory of Chern classes.
When we write the motive of $\mathbf P^1$ as a direct sum of the constant motive with a Tate motive, by definition, the Tate motive is the motive of the 
projective line pointed at infinity. Therefore, its Betti realisation goes to $H^2(\mathbf P^1,\{\infty\},\mathbf Z)$.